# save image with cakephp3

Tags: image, cakephp-3.0

I want to save the image path through a form, but the path of the image is not saved.

i've tried with [this](http://cakemanager.org/docs/utils/1.0/behaviors/uploadable/) but i don't know where to put the code

MultimediaController:

```
public function add()
{
    $multimedia = $this->Multimedia->newEntity();
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $multimedia = $this->Multimedia->patchEntity($multimedia, $this->request->data);

        $file = $_FILES['url'];
        $path = 'files/' .$_FILES['url']['name'];
        move_uploaded_file($this->data['url']['tmp_name'], $path);



        if ($this->Multimedia->save($multimedia)) {
            $this->Flash->success('The multimedia has been saved.');
            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
        } else {
            $this->Flash->error('The multimedia could not be saved. Please, try again.');
        }
    }
    $categories = $this->Multimedia->Categories->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
    $this->set(compact('multimedia', 'categories'));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['multimedia']);

}
```

add.ctp

```
 <?= $this->Form->create($multimedia, array('enctype' => 'multipart/form-data')); ?>
<fieldset>
    <legend><?= __('Add Multimedia') ?></legend>
    <?php
        echo $this->Form->input('title');
        echo $this->Form->input('description');
        echo $this->Form->input('mime_type');
        echo $this->Form->input('filename');
        echo $this->Form->input('url', array('type' => 'file'));

        echo $this->Form->input('category_id', ['options' => $categories]);
        echo $this->Form->input('created_by');

    ?>
</fieldset>
<?= $this->Form->button(__('Submit')) ?>
<?= $this->Form->end() ?>
```

I'm new to cakephp 3 and am a bit lost. Please help.

**Update**:

already achieved to save the image:

```
 $file = $_FILES['url'];
        $path = "webroot\\files\\" .$_FILES['url']['name'];
        print_r($file);
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['url']['tmp_name'], $path);

        if ($this->Multimedia->save($multimedia)) {
            $this->Flash->success('The multimedia has been saved.');
            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
        } else {
            $this->Flash->error('The multimedia could not be saved. Please, try again.');
        }
```

But now the "url" is not saved in the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this help you, the script here has some improvements like using the short deceleration for arrays:

> The Controller code:

```
//don't forget to import the Folder class
use Cake\Filesystem\Folder;

public function add()
{
    $multimedia = $this->Multimedia->newEntity();
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $multimedia = $this->Multimedia->patchEntity($multimedia, $this->request->data);

            //upload script start here
            $mm_dir = new Folder(WWW_ROOT . 'upload_dir', true, 0755);
            $target_path = $mm_dir->pwd() . DS . $this->request->data('url.name');
            move_uploaded_file($this->request->data('url.tmp_name'), $target_path);

            //save the file name in the field 'url'
            $multimedia->url= $this->request->data('url.name');
            //the script ends here

            if ($this->Multimedia->save($multimedia)) {
                    // ............
            } else {
                    // .........
            }
    }
    // ..........
}
```

> add.ctp // improvement

```
<?= $this->Form->create($multimedia, ['type' => 'file']); ?>
echo $this->Form->input('url', ['type' => 'file']);
```